# Android: Broadcast receiver and mobile data?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am implementing a toggle button that turns mobile data on and off (enable/disable).

How shall I do this?
I know how to go about this with wifi from here: android-er.blogspot.in/2011/01/turn-wifi-onoff-using.html?m=1
, so how can I do the same with mobile data. 
if im not wrong ill have to register a broadcast receiver for this right?
how do I register it?